# Measure Power Consumption of Battery Charger?

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, measurement, module

I want to ask how to measure power consumption of battery (Li-On 18650) charger module (TP4056 and USB Boost) and the total power consumption, if i have this circuit:

[image]

I have already know the power drawn of my circuit, lets say its 0.5 Watt (5V * 0.1 A). But how about the charger module and USB boost? Since i couldn't find its datasheet.

References (from ebay):

1. [TP4056 Module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2PCS-5V-1A-USB-18650-Lithium-Battery-Charging-Board-Module-Protection-TP4056/221483898858?hash=item33917817ea:g:CE4AAOSwj9lZuLLw)
2. [USB Boost 5v](https://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-PFM-Control-DC-DC-USB-0-9V-5V-to-5V-dc-Boost-Step-up-Power-Supply-Module/311520400471?epid=1384188923&hash=item4888101457:g:I5IAAOSwBjdaE382)

Thank You

Comment: Use a voltmeter and ammeter.

Comment: 1. Use a USB voltmeter/ammeter module in the USB lead. Cheap and widely available. 
2. Take a USB lead and access the power feed wires. Break the V+ wire and insert an ammeter OR a low value resistor (R ~= 0.1/Iexpected A) (eg 200 mA R ~~= 0.1/0.2 = 0.5 Ohms). Measure voltage from load side of resistor or ammeter to V-. Measure current or drop across resistor to calculate power = V x I. Repeat with and without downstream modules and load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to measure power consumption of battery (Li-On 18650) charger module (TP4056 and USB Boost) and the total power consumption, ...

Method 1. Take a USB lead and access the power feed wires.
Break the V+ wire and insert an ammeter OR a low value resistor
(R ~= 0.1/Iexpected A) (eg 200 mA R ~~= 0.1/0.2 = 0.5 Ohms).

Measure voltage from load side of resistor or ammeter to V-. Measure current or drop across resistor to calculate power = V x I.

Repeat with and without downstream modules and load.

Adding a capacitor from the load side of the resistor to ground will smooth out short term variations. (10 uF - 100 uF typically)

**________________________________________**

Method 2. Use a USB voltmeter/ammeter module in the USB lead. Cheap and widely available.

Many examples on ebay [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ebay+indonesia+usb+voltmeter&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi1p5T09qTiAhXEjOYKHYWOChwQsAR6BAghEAE&biw=1152&bih=606&dpr=1.25)

eg Remarkable value $US4.76 free shipping (from China) [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/6-in-1-USB-Detector-Voltmeter-Ammeter-Power-Capacity-Tester-Power-off-Protection-/112360609821)
[image]

**

Comment: i already had USB tester, but if i measure it in USB lead of USB boost 5v, it will measure current/power of My Circuit (Microcontroller & sensor) NOT TP4056 charger module and USB bootst 5v, right? What i want to measure is TP4056 and USB Boost itself

Comment: @RizalLana Between the equipment that you have and my answer you have all you need. Now you just have to read what I say and think it through. | Read where I say " ... in the power feed wires ..." -> power is fed from left to right. You have a USB cable at left feeding power to the complete setup and a USB cable at right feeding your load. Clearly (hopefully) if you can to measure the power consumption of your charger and boost converter then you need to insert your measurement system in the LEFT HAND = power input USB lead. Go from there ....

Comment: okay, now i got it. Thanks